# Replicating Flask + MongoDB gets Internal Server Error

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm interesting in making a very thin flask interface into my mongo database---just a couple of simple indexes and forms to display and edit my data.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/) from MongoDB, with some supplement [from this one](http://ryaneshea.com/mongodb-for-flask-apps) that was also helpful.

The first time I run `python manage.py runserver`, everything works fine.  But after adding views, and templates, the second time running `python manage.py runserver` the application seems to fail with:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

I have `app.run(debug=True)`, but there's no additional error logging in the console:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
 * Running on http://localhost:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2013 14:45:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2013 14:45:14] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Did anyone else have this problem?  Is there something missing in the tutorial, or is there a better way to figure out where my error is?  Any other advice on setting up a minimal Flask layer over a MongoDB would be appreciated, too!

Comment: I did that tutorial and remember there was some error in it which I had to fix. Can you share your code ?

Comment: Indeed we need to see some code to figure it out. However, this error seems vaguely familiar to me too. The tutorial uses a sort of hack to include the parent directory in the system path, which is done in the manage.py file. Make sure that is set correctly.

Comment: I'll see if I can list the files in a way that makes sense, or upload to github or something.  In the meantime, Teisman, I think you're right about the hack.  I ran the following in interactive command line: `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
` and it had some complaints. `__file__` is not defined.

Comment: You cannot refer to `__file__` directly on command line because it is only defined inside an actual file/module. Try to share your code on github and we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Flask-Slither](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Slither). It aims to be a thin layer between flask and mongodb. Its still in the early stages, but works pretty well.